# How to get voice directions

Tags: settings, maps

With WP 7.5 on Nokia Lumia 920 I had voice directions that said things like "You've gone a different way."  Now I'm on 8.0 and I don't have those any more.  Maybe something else turned them off.  How do I turn them back on?

Comment: What app are you referring to?

Comment: I don't know what app provided the voice.  I thought it was a part of the Microsoft app that provided directions.

Comment: I don't think Microsoft ever provied a navigation app. Another odd point about your post is that the Lumia 920 was never shipped with WP 7.5.

Comment: Aah, that helps my confusion.  I previously had an LG Windows Phone, do you know if that had something like what I've described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which navigation app you used in your LG WP 7.5 phone, but you can have voice guidance with your Lumia 920 by using **Here Drive**.

In Here Drive, select Settings > Navigation voice, and choose the voice you want to use. If needed, press the "Download New" button to get other voices.

Some other instructions that may help you : http://here.com/help/wp8/drive/voice-guidance

Comment: I really don't think it was in Here Drive.

Comment: Of course, in your LG WP 7.5, you had another navigation app (I can't figure out which one). But I think you can have an equivalent with Here Drive in your  new Lumia 920. I slightly updated my answer.