# No voice directions for Windows 10 Maps if use bluetooth

Tags: windows-10-mobile, bluetooth, maps, blu-win-hd

I have BLU Win HD LTE. Recently I upgraded it to Windows 10 and now trying to use Windows Maps. It works fine, but no voice at all.

I read [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-win_maps/no-voice-directions-for-windows-10-maps/b943ec47-6a92-4669-919c-d273aaaa1fe5?page=1) and [this](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2969/how-to-get-voice-directions) and checked all settings, for example Speech language: English (US) is default, and I have GPS.

Just found out that voice direction doesn't work when my phone uses bluetooth in my car (hands free system). When I disable bluetooth it works.

Can I have voice directions and bluetooth at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Settings -> Devices -> Bluetooth
2. Click "Advanced"
3. Check "use alternate Bluetooth audio connection for Speech"

Comment: just checked, it works! and I hear voice directions in car's speakers.